# How to set a timeout on fopen with named pipes

Tags: php, linux, ipc, fopen

I am trying to do some IPC in PHP using named pipes.  I have a named pipe created via

```
$pipePath = __DIR__ . '/pipe';
posix_mkfifo($pipePath, 0600);
```

There is another process that should write to that pipe after finishing some computation.  I can wait for it to finish and read the result with something like:

```
$result = file_get_contents($pipePath);
```

or the more verbose

```
$in = fopen($pipePath, 'r');
$result = fread($in, 8192);
fclose($in);
```

(I have simplified the second approach; in the real code I would check for errors, run `fread` in a loop in case the result is > 8192 bytes, etc.)

However, while the other process *should* finish, I don't trust it to be successful, so I want to have a timeout on trying to read the result.  After waiting for some time, I want to give up and report an error saying it crashed, etc.  With the two approaches given, the PHP code will hang forever (or for a *very* long time) waiting for something to write to the pipe.  Specifically, `file_get_contents` and `fread` will hang.

The only solution I was able to come up with is something like this:

```
$timeout = 10; //seconds
for ($i = 0; $i < $timeout; $i++) {
    $in = @fopen($pipePath, 'rn');
    if ($in) break;
    sleep(1);
}
if (!$in) {
   throw new RuntimeException("The other process did not finish in the allotted time");
}
$result = fread($in, 8192);
fclose($in);
```

This uses the undocumented `'n'` flag to `fopen` as shown in one of the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25249892/3113342).  It causes the `fopen` call to fail immediately if it would block.

However, I don't like this solution for two reasons:

1. It does unnecessary work by checking the pipe every second.
2. If the computation in the other process takes 1.01 seconds to complete, this will wait a full 2 seconds to get the result.  For some things that I want to do, this is enough wasted time that it is worth trying to fix the issue.

When `fopen` is called on a URL, I have the ability to add a context parameter the specifies a timeout value.  However, this doesn't seem to work for this, nor does setting the default socket timeout.

Is there a better way to do this with pipes?  If not, I may consider switching to Unix sockets, but those are not so easy to support in the other process so I would rather not do this.

(FYI, I am only concerned with Linux; no need to have something that works on Windows or anything else, in case this matters.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one way to do this...

First, I didn't know about the `n` flag, this was very useful info!

However, it is not exactly true that the function fails if it would block. It still returns a file handle. We can use the file handle and pass it to the `stream_select` function to wait for data to become available.

Something like this:

```
$f=fopen("my.fifo","rn");
$r=array($f);
$w=array();
$x=array();
stream_select($r,$w,$x,10);
```

This code waits for 10 seconds for someone else to write to the other end of the fifo.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of using select. I think part of the problem was that my question originally claimed that `fopen` would hang, but really it was `fread` that was hanging.